# CORS Policy Error in Flask SocketIO and Angular socket.io-client

Tags: angular, websocket, cors, flask-socketio, flask-cors

I'm trying to learn websocket using Flask and Angular but couldn't solve the CORS problem. Even though I allow CORS, my Angular client websocket cannot connect to Flask server websocket. Below, I added my codes abouts Angular and Flask. Both of them are extremely simple since I'm just trying to establish a connection.

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin 

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
CORS(app)

@socketio.on('message')
@cross_origin()
def handle_message(data):
    print('received message: ' + data)
    send("test message that should be sent")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="localhost")
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messageList">
    <li>
        {{message}}
    </li>
  </div>
  
  <input
    [(ngModel)]="newMessage"
    (keyup)="$event.keyCode == 13 && sendMessage()"
  />
  <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WebsocketService } from './services/websocket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  newMessage = '';
  messageList: string[] = [];

  constructor(private websocket: WebsocketService){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.websocket.getNewMessage().subscribe((message: string) => {
      this.messageList.push(message);
    })
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.websocket.sendMessage(this.newMessage);
    this.newMessage = '';
  }
}
```

**websocket.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {

  public message$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  constructor() {}

  socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

  public sendMessage(message: any) {
    console.log('sendMessage: ', message)
    this.socket.emit('message', message);
  }

  public getNewMessage = () => {
    this.socket.on('message', (message) =>{
      this.message$.next(message);
    });

    return this.message$.asObservable();
  };
}
```

Finally, this is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgHtu.png)

Comment: The first error is a 403. Any idea what is that about? I don't believe the Python Socket.IO server ever returns 403, so my guess is that this is coming from your side. Maybe it is that `@cross_origin` decorator that you put in the Socket.IO event handler, which shouldn't be there.The CORS error appears because the 403 response does not include CORS headers. The real problem is the 403, not the CORS error.

Comment: After your comment, I found the issue and posted the solution. Thanks for the different perspective :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My computer is macOS and apparently, there is a service named AirPlay Receiver  which uses port 5000. It was "trolling" my websocket server and causing the issue. Either you can disable it in System Preferences > Sharing > AirPlay Receiver or change the port on the server side. I never tried the second solution because when I checked port status I was already running the server.py which was misleading me.